# why does http request fails even when we just googled something like "web", or it is meant to be

Tags: google-chrome, http, jmeter, web-inspector

I have gone to google and searched 'web' in order to see how the HTTP request (by going to → inspect element → Fetch/XHR) sent to server behaves and how many requests (Ctrl + R if you cannot see) are sent by just googling, and I have found that there are these requests which are in red means failed HTTP request so why are they failing or are they meant to fail ?

I was trying to search 'web' in google and saw that the HTTP request sent were failing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [MS Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/edge) browser:

[image]

as you can see all requests are successful.

- Retry on "clean" browser session (no cookies, no cache, no plugins, especially ad blockers like [uBlock Origin](https://ublockorigin.com/)). If you still experience the issues - the problem is on your organization or ISP side
- If the errors are connected with using JMeter as the proxy - make sure to import JMeter's certificate into your browser like it's described in **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation. Alternatively you can try [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), it's not that invasive and doesn't require proxies and certificates manipulations